# WeChat how to send message through open platform?

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram, wechat-auth

i want to know the process

should i really pay 99 dollars each per account(if i have several accounts and message each account's friends list) for developer open platform auth?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Both of developer open platform and wechat-official-account need pay per year.

2.If you have wechat-official-account,you can register wechat-miniprogram-account with the company information of wechat-official-account.So you don't pay for it.

Wechat open platform supports you the only unionid in your different applications include wechat-official-account,wechat-miniprogram,webapp,ios & android apps, Third-party-platform.

If you want to message between two apps,you can get and cache the unionid from different apps.And then you can develop your functions.